# Python web scraping, getting a FileNotFound error

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to run the following script to get some book data from goodreads.com starting with just a list of titles. I have had this code working recently but am now getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "/home/l/gDrive/AudioBookReviews/WebScraping/GoodreadsScraper.py", line 3, in 
    reload(sys)
NameError: name 'reload' is not defined

Here is the Code: https://pastebin.com/Y5NQiVEp

Comment: The directory `/home/l/Downloads/WebScraping` doesn't exist, or the program doesn't have permission to access it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets do a file existence check and access check as follows:

```
import os

filePathStr = '/home/l/Downloads/WebScraping/GoodReadsBooksNew.csv'
if os.path.isfile(): 
    if os.access(filePathStr, os.R_OK):
        print("File exists and is readable")
        fileHandle = open(filePathStr, "w+")
    else:
        print("ERROR: File exists and is NOT readable")
else:
    print("Creating output file "+filePathStr)
    fileHandle = open(filePathStr, "w+")
```

Comment: `'w'` creates the file if it doesn't exist.  This isn't the problem.

Comment: This code still has problems if the directory `/home/l/Downloads/WebScraping` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

as the error states [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Could be permissions or your path is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The error is `FileNotFoundError`. Therefore, your python code is not able to find a file in your machine.

Check the path you are providing when calling `open`, which is this part of the error message `/home/l/Downloads/WebScraping/GoodReadsBooksNew.csv`.

Comment: Yes but that file is there 100%

Comment: Use the `pathlib` module instead of a string for writing paths. You can also go on your terminal, go to the `cd` to the directory with that CSV. Then run this command: `echo $(pwd)/"GoodReadsBooksNew.csv"` which will give you the exact full path to that file. This will not work if you are in a Windows. I assume you are not, given how your path is laid out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure file path exists, and write the file under this directory. Make some modifications of the function `create_csv_file()`.

```
import os
def create_csv_file():
    header = ['Title', 'URL']
    directory = '/home/l/Downloads/WebScraping'
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)
    with open(os.path.join(directory,'GoodReadsBooksNew.csv'), 'w') as csv_file:
        wr = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
        wr.writerow(header)
```